# setState not clearing selected values - React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state

I have a button that submits selected values to api. Once this has been submitted I am then trying to turn button state to disable and rest the values selected back to original state before nay where selected.

This is what I am doing on upload handle:

```
  handleStatusEditsUpload = () => {
    const { value, status } = this.state;

    this.setState({
      value: selected,
      status: {}
    });
  };
```

In my real version locally status is clearing, status is used when changing all values at the same time by clicking the header title, a dialog appears to change all values in that column.

The main one I am having trouble is with the value. Value is populated with a new array that looks at table cell and row.

Here is demo to my project: https://codesandbox.io/s/50pl0jy3xk

Why isnt the state changing? any help appreciated as always.

Comment: selected is not defined in your code snippet

Comment: it is a constant on top

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is happening is that you are mutating state in your "handleValue" method.

```
const newValue = [...this.state.value]; // this holds reference 
newValue[rowIdx][cellIdx] = val; // so that here your state is mutated ( and const "selected" with it)
```

In the long term you probably should change your data structure a bit, so it would be easier to merge updates in to your state value. But a quick fix would be to clone the state value before mutating it:

```
handleValue = (event, val, rowIdx, cellIdx) => {
    const newValue = _.cloneDeep(this.state.value); // no reference anymore
    newValue[rowIdx][cellIdx] = val; // update the cloned value
    this.setState({
      value: newValue
    });
  };
```

Comment: Great catch. I had no idea that original ref would still exist when initiating state from a variable but makes complete sense when you think about it.

Comment: Thanks guys makes sense. The quick fix does not seem to work in this case. cloneDeep

Comment: Oh, you have another bug with your code example: replace your submit buttons onClick with onClick={this.handleStatusEditsUpload}.  If you need to use props in this method, you don't need to pass them from render, but you can directly use this.props in the method.

Answer (score 0):

I just ran your code in the sandbox you provided and it's throwing errors when you click the confirm button (trying to spread non-iterable). Once that is corrected, the state updates correctly. See my fork below:

https://codesandbox.io/s/385y99575m

I've left in a few console logs so you can see the component state updating  when your `onClick` fires.

Why are you passing in your props to the `handleStatusEditsUpload` method? It doesn't take an argument. Was this just part of your debugging process?

Comment: Think I might have misunderstood your question here. What value are you expecting to return from your state update? According to the code, you want the array of objects which each has three properties. Right now, that's not working as somehow your `selected` const is being updated. How on earth that is happening, I have no idea.

Comment: Thanks @tombraider